# How can I add two values in a list in C++ using rbegin() and advance(iterator,1)?

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to calculate the fibonacci series using a list in C++, as instructed.
I was left with notes on how to improve it, and I simply don't understand what is being asked of me. How can i use rbegin() and advance(iterator,1) to add previous values and calculate a new one?

Here is what I had earlier.

list mutableFibonacci(int position)
{

```
list<int> series;
int first = 0; //Remove
int second = 1; //Remove

for (int i = 1; i <= position; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
        series.push_back(1);
    else
    {                                   
      //We can get the last value and the value before from the series, like      so, series.rbegin();  then get the value from the reverse iterator. Then we can call advance(iterator, 1) to get to the previous value. We can get the second to last value.
        series.push_back(first + second);
        first = second;
        second = series.back();

    }
}
return series;
```

}

Here is what I tried to do to fix it.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= position; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
        series.push_back(1);
    else
    {                                   


        int last = series.rbegin();
        int previous = advance(series, 1);
        series.push_back(last + previous);
    }
}
return series;
```

Comment: It would help to see what you have already tried. Can you add the code that you're currently using, or at least an excerpt showing the problem that you're having?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Images of code aren't helpful, better to use `copy/paste` commands to post code exactly as it is

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, because people trying to answer your question will want to copy from that. With a screen shot of your code, you make it unnecessarily complicated for them.

Comment: sorry guys. I just created a stackoverflow account. I will update it

Comment: it's updated @ArnavBorborah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 series.push_back(1);
 series.push_back(1);

 for (int i = 3; i <= position; ++i){                     //First 2 elements inititalised
    list<int>::reverse_iterator it = series.rbegin();     //End of the list
    list<int>::reverse_iterator it2 = it;                 //Copy the iterator
    advance(it2,1);                                       //Move the iterator
    series.push_back(*(it)+*(it2));                       //Add the sum
}
```

Without the `int` it can look like this. The `auto` from before is a C++11 shortcut to defining types for variables (thus instead of having to type `list<int>::reverse_iterator` I can type `auto`)

Comment: Can you explain what "auto" does. And are pointers necessary, I was told to delete the int first and int second from my code.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you :)

Comment: Fibonacci does not start with 0

Comment: In my case, it's supposed to start at 1

Answer (score 0):

First of all your initialization is incorrect, you need to initialize at least 2 elements, or `std::advance()` would have Undefined Behaviour:

```
if (i < 3)
    series.push_back(1);
```

`rbegin()` will give iterator (in this case reverse one), not `int`, which semantically behaves like a pointer:

```
list<int>::reverse_iterator it = series.rbegin();
int last = *it;
std::advance( it, 1 );
series.push_back( last + *it );
```

not sure, why `std::advance()` is recommended, `std::next()` would fit better here.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you for the clarification